# Toggle onChange only when interacted with

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data, swiftui-toggle

I am displaying a checklist that allows the user to check options on and off:

```
ForEach(checklist.items.sorted(by: { $0.sortOrder < $1.sortOrder })) { item in
    @Bindable var item = item
    Toggle(item.title, isOn: $item.isChecked)
    .toggleStyle(CheckboxToggleStyle())
    .onChange(of: item.isChecked) { newValue in
        checklistChanged()
    }
}

func checklistChanged() {
    //check some things and update other parts of the UI
}
```

This works fine. However, the checklist is a SwiftData @Model which has a method to reset the checklist:

```
func reset() {
    for item in self.items {
        item.isChecked = false
    }
}
```

And calling this function causes the `checklistChanged()` function in my view to get called (multiple times) because the `isChecked` property is being changed on all the items. I only want the `checklistChanged()` func to be called specifically when a user taps and changes a checkbox value. How can I separate these concerns? I tried using `onTapGesture` instead of `onChange` on the toggle but that doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tell the difference between the `Toggle` changing `isChecked`, vs your code changing `isChecked`. You need some extra information to indicate who changed it.

The simplest way is to just add a `@Transient` property to your model, to indicate whether `isChecked` has been programmatically changed.

```
@Transient
var programmaticallyChanged: Bool = false
```

If you need to scale this up for all the properties in your model, you can write a member macro that is attached to your `@Model` class to generate these.

You can set this in `reset`:

```
func reset() {
    for item in self.items {
        if item.isChecked {
            item.isChecked = false
            item.programmaticallyChanged = true
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can check for this flag in `onChange`:

```
.onChange(of: item.isChecked) {
    if item.programmaticallyChanged {
        item.programmaticallyChanged = false
    } else {
        checklistChanged()
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that it is important to only set `programmaticallyChanged` to true if the property has actually changed by the call to reset(), that is from true to false, because onChanged will only be called for objects where `isChecked` has actually changed so for the rest `programmaticallyChanged` would not be set to false again which could lead to an unpredictable behaviour if the item was later changed

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That is a very good point. I totally forgot to consider that.